# SQL Managed Instance Restore to lower environments

Tags: restore, azure-sql-managed-instance

I was trying to find an article or design pattern to fit my use case but I cannot find one.

My use case: I have a Production Subscription with a SQL Managed Instance that holds all production data.  Then I have a Dev/Test subscription that has one SQL Managed Instance for Dev and Test environments.  From what I'm reading I can't use PITR to automate the restore to lower environments if they are in a different subscription.  COPY_ONLY might be able to work if you set a custom TDE key?  I'm fairly surprised no one has written an article on how to accomplish this either, it seems like a very common design pattern?  Does anyone have advice on how this might be accomplished without decrypting the db?

I found this article but it doesn't really explain the design pattern for restoring MI to lower environments in a different subscription. [Cross Subscription PITR](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/246989/sql-managed-instance-cross-subscription-restores-migration?newreg=4b2c203163bf480585bd30e1783b3dee)